# Comparing column names in Pyspark

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe created from a source file.

I have another dataframe created from a table in the database.

The source file may at occasions have new columns added into it.

for example: the source file today has the below columns

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
```

after a few months the source file has the below columns

```
col1,col2,col5,col3,col4,col6
```

**Note**: the order of the newly added columns can be changed also, they may or may not be necessarily at the end of the file.

i want to compare these columns to my dataframe from the database (df2) (which has static columns) and want the names of the newly added columns in a dataframe.

(I keep adding columns to the data table regularly, so any new columns are added into the database.)

currently i am doing the following

```
set(df1) - set(df2)
```

which gives the below

```
col5,col6
```

Column names of the newly added columns, but i cannot convert these column names into dataframe so that i can ingest the new column names into the database table

(just the column names to be ingested - to notify the user that there are new columns in the source file)
Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me.

```
df = set(df1) - set(df2)
df3 = spark.createDataFrame(df,StringType())
```